# RSpec: Authenticating before test with devise_auth_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, devise

I am using [devise_auth_token](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) to authenticate users for an API. I would like to authenticate users before each test is run, but keep getting a 401 error. When I use postman to the endpoint with the correct headers, it works, but fails to work during tests.

```
before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

def get_auth
  headers = @user.create_new_auth_token
  auth = Hash.new
  auth["client"] = headers["client"]
  auth["access-token"] = headers["access-token"]
  auth["uid"] = headers["uid"]
  auth["expiry"] = headers["expiry"]
  return auth
end

it "auth user should return success" do
    get 'get_tasks_for_user', params: {uid: @user.uid}, headers: get_auth
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
end
```

RSpec

```
TasksController auth user should return success
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status 200
       expected the response to have status code 200 but it was 401
```

Comment: Can't you use `sign_in @user` in `before(:each)` block?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper method

```
#/spec/support/helpers/session_helper.rb
module SessionHelper

  def set_request_headers(resp)
    { 'ACCEPT' => "application/json",
      'Content-Type' => "application/json",
      'access-token' => resp['access-token'],
      'token-type' => resp['token-type'],
      'client' => resp['client'],
      'expiry' => resp['expiry'],
      'uid' => resp['uid']
    }
  end

  def subdomain_login(uid, password, subdomain)
    request_params = {
      'email' => uid,
      'password' => password
    }
    host! "#{subdomain}.lvh.me"
    post "/portal/auth/sign_in", params: request_params
    return set_request_headers(response.headers)
  end
end
```

Make sure you have the following entry in your `/spec/rails_helper`

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.include SessionHelper, :type => :request
end
```

You can use `subdomain_login` in your tests. Here is an Rspec example.

```
post '/portal/system/locations', params: request_params.to_json,
  headers: subdomain_login(user_id, password, subdomain)
```