# Unable to update a user in Rspec with Devise and DeviseTokenAuth, although create and delete work fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5 app I'm using these gems among others:

```
gem "devise", "~> 4.2.0"
gem "devise_token_auth"
```

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

I'm unable to create an Rspec request to update a User. Whatever I've tried, it's failed:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
describe "PATCH #update" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested user" do
        u1 = create(:user)
        patch :update, params: { id: u1.to_param, user: attributes_for(:user, name: "name_new", email: "email_new@mail.com") },
              format: :json

        u1.reload
        expect(u1.name).to eq("name_new")
      end
    end
```

The thing is that a test for creating and deleting a User works well. Only updating doesn't.

It's sending the new parameters during the patch request, but the returned parameters of a User are always the old ones. What the error is -- I have no idea, it just says the test fails. And again -- only one for updating.

I've tried to use PUT and POST -- still failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need `password` and `password_confirmation` to update devise user by default. Try pass them in.

> This route will update an existing user's account settings. The default accepted params are password and password_confirmation, but this can be customized using the devise_parameter_sanitizer system. If config.check_current_password_before_update is set to :attributes the current_password param is checked before any update, if it is set to :password the current_password param is checked only if the request updates user password.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Rspec test I had written some time back.

```
  it 'updates a user\'s email_address and password' do
    new_password = Faker::Internet.password(8)
    email_address = Faker::Internet.email

    request_params = {
      'email' => email_address,
      'name' => Faker::Name.name,
      'password' => new_password,
      'password_confirmation' => new_password
    }

    put '/myapp/v1/system/auth', request_params.to_json, subdomain_login(user.uid, password, account.subdomain)
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)

    # Validating the password update with sign_in
    request_params = {
      'email' => email_address,
      'password' => new_password
    }

    post '/myapp/v1/system/auth/sign_in', request_params.to_json,
      { 'ACCEPT' => "application/json",
        'Content-Type' => "application/json" }

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
  end
```

Here is the transcript from console

**Initial user**

```
#<Myapp::V1::System::User id: "13153737-9efb-47e2-8ac9-85aa28befa2b", provider: "email", uid: "olin@schneiderbailey.name", name: nil, nickname: nil, image: nil, email: "olin@schneiderbailey.name", created_at: "2017-01-13 11:50:01", updated_at: "2017-01-13 11:50:01">
```

**Update Params**

```
{"email"=>"lisa@turner.info", "name"=>"Norberto Zulauf", "password"=>"OnT3Zv19YpZ", "password_confirmation"=>"OnT3Zv19YpZ"}
```

**Response Body**

```
"{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"id\":\"13153737-9efb-47e2-8ac9-85aa28befa2b\",\"email\":\"lisa@turner.info\",\"name\":\"Norberto Zulauf\",\"provider\":\"email\",\"uid\":\"lisa@turner.info\",\"nickname\":null,\"image\":null,\"created_at\":\"2017-01-13T11:50:01.175Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-01-13T11:50:03.436Z\"}}"
```

Please note that the registrations controller (which also updates the user) is overridden to meet a specific requirement.

Add `faker` gem, if needed to try the code. Refer to this thread for `subdomain_login` helper

[RSpec: Authenticating before test with devise_auth_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370623/rspec-authenticating-before-test-with-devise-auth-token/41608434#41608434)